# Subtracting duration from a timestamp in SQL

Tags: sql

I have a timestamp in a column say **T1**(T1 = '07-04-2022 13:04:11'). In SQL I need to subtract a duration **D** (5 SECOND) from this timestamp and use it in a query as a variable.

| NAME | DATE_TIME |
| --- | --- |
| Person A | '07-04-2022 13:04:**09**' |
| Person B | '07-04-2022 13:04:**12**' |
| Person C | '07-04-2022 13:04:**04**' |

*Current query*

```
Select * from TABLE_A where DATE_TIME >= to_date(T1, 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
```

*Required query*

```
Select NAME from TABLE_A where DATE_TIME >= to_date(T1, 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss') -  D
```

*Required Output is*

| NAME |
| --- |
| Person A |
| Person B |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `TIMESTAMPDIFF` along with `ABS` here:

```sql
SELECT NAME
FROM TABLE_A
WHERE ABS(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, DATE_TIME, '2022-04-07 13:04:11')) <= 5;
```

Edit: If you really stored those timestamps as *text*, then you'll need to convert `DATE_TIME` to a date first in my answer:

```sql
SELECT NAME
FROM TABLE_A
WHERE ABS(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,
                        STR_TO_DATE(DATE_TIME, '%d-%m-%Y %H:%i:%s),
                        '2022-04-07 13:04:11')) <= 5;
```

Note that your timestamp literals in the question are malformed and won't be interpreted by MySQL correctly.  You should use an ISO format as I have done in my answer above.

Comment: I agree, but that's the problem I need answer to. Timestamp format can not be changed